# How do I get google script to pull the whole gmail messages under the label?

Tags: google-apps-script

The script created in Google apps script works but it is only pulling about 600 emails information and transferring it to the my google sheet. I have about 7,000 email nested under that label. How would I modify the script to get all 7,000 emails to import onto my google sheet?

I was looking into using a nextPageToken but am not sure how to implement it. Everything I've tried thus does not seem to work.

```
function ExtractingEmails(query="Label:Inbox") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject"]];
  const ts = GmailApp.search(query);
  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject()])
    })
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry to bother you again but when I tried to run the macro again It took longer than 6 min and cancelled out. Would there be a way to put a date range on the emails I want to pull. Thank you if you can help I really appreciate it.

Comment: About your new question, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'll be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike I posted a new question thank you for the advice again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77733105/how-can-i-modify-this-script-to-pull-a-certain-date-range-of-emails-instead-of-e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about using 2nd and 3rd arguments as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ExtractingEmails(query = "Label:Inbox") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject"]];

  // --- I modified the below script.
  let start = 0;
  const max = 500;
  let ts = [];
  do {
    const t = GmailApp.search(query, start, max);
    start += max;
    ts = [...ts, ...t];
  } while (ts.length == start);
  // ---

  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject()])
    })
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)