# How can I modify this script to pull a certain date range of emails instead of everything nested under the label?

Tags: google-apps-script

The problem I'm running into is that when I run the script in google sheets the macro takes longer than 6 minutes due to the quantity of emails nested under the label. The only way I could think to reduce that time below 6 minutes would be to pull them in batches. I'm not sure if that is the only way but would appreciate any new ideas or a way to execute my current idea.

I tried reducing the number of emails and while that works I cannot get the back-end of emails to populate on the google sheets after that. I tied looking up how to extend the maximum of 6 minute runtime on macros but could not successfully execute that.

```
function ExtractingEmails(query = "Label:Inbox") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject"]];

  // --- I modified the below script.
  let start = 0;
  const max = 500;
  let ts = [];
  do {
    const t = GmailApp.search(query, start, max);
    start += max;
    ts = [...ts, ...t];
  } while (ts.length == start);
  // ---

  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject()])
    })
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to retrieve the emails by giving the date range, how about the following modification?

In this case, I used the search query of `after` and `before`. Also, I think that you can also use `newer` and `older`. [Ref](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

#### Modified script:

In this modification, to the value of `query`, the emails from 2023/11/01 to 2023/11/30 are retrieved.

```js
function ExtractingEmails(query = "Label:Inbox") {

  const after = "2023/11/01"; // Added
  const before = "2023/11/30"; // Added
  query += ` after:${after} before:${before}`; // Added

  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject"]];

  let start = 0;
  const max = 500;
  let ts = [];
  do {
    const t = GmailApp.search(query, start, max);
    start += max;
    ts = [...ts, ...t];
  } while (ts.length == start);

  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject()]);
    });
  });
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)